# Java: Can I perform an XSLT transformation based on href attribute?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a `xml` file of the following form:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/path/to/transformer.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
Content...
```

When I open the file in a browser, it automatically parses it correctly based on `/path/to/transformer.xsl`.

I want to write a Java program that takes a path to a `xml` file and produces `html` output based on the `href` attribute in `xml-stylesheet`. In pseudocode:

```
private void transform(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
  // Open a xml file found in inputPath
  // Perform an XSLT transformation based on the href attribute
  // Write the result to a html file in outputPath
}
```

I am aware that this probably could be done by getting the attribute value using a regular expression, but I was looking for a neater way of doing it. I want to consider the whole `xml-stylesheet` and perform the transformation the way the browser does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JAXP API, `TransformerFactory.getAssociatedStylesheet()` will take the source document as input and return a `Source` object for the stylesheet referenced in the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction. You can then compile this stylesheet in the usual way using `factory.newTemplates()` or `factory.newTransformer()`.

Saxon's s9api interface has a similar method `XsltCompiler.getAssociatedStylesheet()`.